# What is the inflation rate based on the current CPI?

Tags: united-states, inflation

In April, the Consumer Price Index reached a record high of 4.2%.

My questions are:

1. Is this 4.2%, the inflation in the US now?
2. Where can I find the inflation rate since 2005?

Comment: "record high" is overstating.  This is the highest reported CPI since 2008; it is nothing like the inflation rates in the 1970's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bureau of labor statistics releases the inflation numbers for the United States](https://www.bls.gov/cpi/).

> The Consumer Price Index (CPI) is a measure of the average change over
> time in the prices paid by urban consumers for a market basket of
> consumer goods and services. Indexes are available for the U.S. and
> various geographic areas. Average price data for select utility,
> automotive fuel, and food items are also available.

The site has links to all sorts of databases and reports. This is a good place to start looking for historical data.

Comment: Is CPI the inflation, or is it a derived value from CPI?

Comment: @wonderfulworld CPI is a measurement of inflation based on an average over a broad range of costs.